# QGIS crashing when opening Layer Properties in v2.14 and after upgrading to 2.18

Tags: qgis, osx

I have a similar problem to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200430/stopping-qgis-crashes-when-opening-layer-properties-after-adding-svg-paths/219065#219065) I believe the issue began after I re-arranged my directory structure (which included some .shp files).

Now I am unable to open any layer properties in any .qgs document, even after upgrading to 2.18 as per [these instructions](http://www.underdiverwaterman.com/clean-install-of-qgis-in-osx/) as well as [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).

I am running OSX 10.11.5

Answer (score 4):

First of all I had to [show my User>Library directory as it was hidden on OSX](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3983467?start=0&tstart=0). Then i deleted org.qgis.qgis2.plist from User>Library>Preferences> Relaunched QGIS and so far so good (but early days). WARNING This will delete preferences, but was worth it to get QGIS back up and running.